# Helm is not deleting release

Tags: kubernetes-helm

**OS - MAC, Helm Version - v2.14.2, Tiller v2.14.2**

I am trying to remove `jaeger` using helm, but as soon as I am executing the below command, nothing is showing in console.

`helm del --purge jaeger`

[image]

After waiting for a few mins, the below error is coming.

`Error: context deadline exceeded`

The same thing happing with `helm ls --all jaeger` command as well.

Comment: Could you please add the tiller version. You can get that using `helm version`

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi : Tiller is updated with helm client. Version v2.14.2

Comment: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2409#issuecomment-323436068 could be related. Are you on GKE?

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi No I am on local